# How to replace new line break with '\n'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

And I checked that because of this

```
  currentMd: '<div>#hehe


  </div>'
```

The two extra new line that is in the `currentMd` breaking it, so how can I instead replacing that new lines with `\n` ??

So it will be like this instead

```
  currentMd: '<div>#hehe\n\n</div>'
```

In javascript or jQuery would be fine.

It may be not clear that the content is actually just an example here.

The actual content is being retrieved from a database, so in the database there I won't have control and the user will always press enter anyway.

---

## EDIT:

I might have not been very clear on my question here.

The thing is that this content that being assign to `contentMd` it is being retrieved from `nodejs` which I have no control on what is going in there.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it.

Comment: That's actually 3 line breaks, not 2.

Comment: @jcsanyi The thing is that the content is being retrieve from a database :/

Comment: @Ali: Then the answer depends on how the database is getting its content, and what part of the code is coming from the database.

Comment: @jcsanyi this is in nodejs

Comment: Please include the node.js code that you're using to read and output the value from the database. The problem is somewhere there. I've added the node.js tag now, so this question should get some extra attention from node.js experts now.

Comment: I think the confusion is because we have no context - we don't know what currentMd is or why you're trying to execute it. Is this a value that's retrieved via ajax? Is it generated directly in the source of the page?

Comment: @jcsanyi currentMd is a variable that would be used to insert the content that it receives from `nodejs` to the editor. It is a Markdown editor and the problem is that when they first create a new post they do have new lines, but when I want to get it back to the editor it doesn't accept these new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
var your_content = "<div>#hehe\
    \
    \
    </div>";
var replaced_text = your_content.replace(/\n|\s/g, "");
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/A4Hk8/

Comment: It doesn't work because the content already execute in the JavaScript file :(

Comment: Actually I figured that I should do this in the server not in the client side and it works :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go into your text editor and replace the line breaks by hand. Unless this code is computer-generated, or you somehow managed to make this bug in thousands of lines of code before catching it, that should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how you do it:

```
> '<div>#hehe\n\n</div>'
"<div>#hehe

</div>"
```

Comment: The thing is that the content is being retrieve from a database :/

Comment: @Ali: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you printing it out directly into your JS file? If so, that's not the way to go about it. You can't fix invalid JavaScript with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not, this is being retrieved from the server side.

Comment: @Ali: You can't fix invalid JavaScript with JavaScript. Fix the way your server is outputting it.